# How do I print out lists with a specific quality?

Tags: python, list, element

Let's say we have 4 lists:

```
["LA","California"]
["NV","Nevada"]
["NY","New York"]
["SF","California"]
```

How do I write a code that prints out ONLY the 1st and 4th lists, BECAUSE both of them have `"California"` as the 2nd element?

Comment: **Index of answers** 1. [If you know negative indexes in lists check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29192260/4099593) 2. [If you want a simple approach check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29192265/4099593) 3. [If you want list comprehensions check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29192268/4099593) 4. [If you know about `filter` check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29192322/4099593). After choosing mark the answer you found as the best as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a list of lists:

```
list_of_lists = [["LA","California"],
                 ["NV","Nevada"],
                 ["NY","New York"],
                 ["SF","California"]]
```

Then, you can print out only the lists that have `"California"` in the last position:

```
for L in list_of_lists:
    if L[-1] == "California":
        print(L)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L = [["LA","California"]
["NV","Nevada"],
["NY","New York"],
["SF","California"]]
for list1 in L:
    if list1[1] == "California":
        print list1
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have list of lists

```
>>> l = [["LA","California"],
["NV","Nevada"],
["NY","New York"],
["SF","California"]]
>>> [i for i in l if i[1] == 'California']
[['LA', 'California'], ['SF', 'California']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function

```
>>> l = [["LA","California"],
... ["NV","Nevada"],
... ["NY","New York"],
... ["SF","California"]]
>>> list(filter(lambda x:x[1]=="California",l))
[['LA', 'California'], ['SF', 'California']]
```